# How to populate ViewDataDictionary inside an ExceptionFilter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

**How to retrieve the ViewModel from within an exception filter?**

I have an ExceptionFilter, which I am using for a global error handler in an asp .net core 3.1 MVC application. I am trying to get the exception filter to redirect back to the View when there is an error and show validation errors, ie the equivalent of saying:

```
return View(viewModel)
```

in the controller

I can redirect to the View, but am a little stuck on how to populate the Model in the ViewResult

ExceptionFilter code

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();       

        if (context.Exception is WebServiceException && context.Exception.IsUnauthorized())
        {
            context.Result =  new  RedirectToActionResult("fetchtoken", "Home", new { path = $"/{controller}/{action}" });
        }
        //other type of exception, return the view displaying errors
        else
        {
            context.ModelState.Clear();
            context.ModelState.AddModelError(action, $"error in {action}");
            m_Logger.LogError(context.Exception, $"error in {action}");
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            context.ModelState
            context.Result = new ViewResult{
                ViewName = action,
                ViewData = // ??????????????
            };
            
        }
        
    }
```

**In the controller:**

```
  [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthoriseApiUser(AuthoriseApiViewModel viewModel)
    {
        await m_ApiUserService.AuthoriseUser(viewModel.TenantId, viewModel.UserId); //error thrown here
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which generate the exception?  Because ModelState itself can pass the model and errors

Comment: There is no exception, I just need to find a way to pass the model into ViewData. I can do ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(m_ModelMetadataProvider, context.ModelState), but this doesn't populate the model

Answer (score 1):

Through obtaining the value of each key in the form data, the value is compared with the property of the model. Then, assign value to model. For example.

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        string controller = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        
        //start
        var viewModel = new ViewModel();
        var list = context.HttpContext.Request.Form.AsEnumerable();
        foreach (var meta in list)
        {
            if (meta.Key == "addr")
            {
                viewModel.addr = meta.Value;
            }
        }
        //end
        if (context.Exception is WebServiceException && context.Exception.IsUnauthorized())
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("fetchtoken", "Home", new { path = $"/{controller}/{action}" });
        }
        //other type of exception, return the view displaying errors
        else
        {
            //...
            var modelMetadata = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
            context.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = action,
                ViewData = ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadata, context.ModelState)
                {
                    Model = viewModel
                }
            };

        }

    }
```

Model

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string addr { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the viewmodel isn't in the RouteData, it is a Form POST. The context.HttpContext contains the form data, but not sure how to turn it back into a model

Comment: How does form post transfer in the exception filter, because the default modelstate does not trigger the exception filter.

Comment: The error is when the code inside the action tries to call a service method using the model. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @jazza1000,this process is equivalent to model binding.

Comment: Can you accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?